# Creating methods in C#, problems with syntax, brackets, and passing

Tags: c#, methods, module

I'm trying to create a simple program in Visual Studio to add various car payments together and then calculate an annual cost and use methods.

I'm have some trouble with the braces and if I am properly passing variables.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            double loanPayment = 0;
            double insurance = 0;
            double gas = 0;
            double oil = 0;
            double tires = 0;
            double maintenance = 0;
            double monthlyTotal = 0;
            double annualTotal = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following expenses on a per month basis");
            {
                getInput(loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintenance);
                calculate(monthlyTotal, annualTotal);
                Console.WriteLine("Your monthly total is ${0:F2} and your annual total is ${1:F2}", monthlyTotal, annualTotal);
        }
    }//endMain


    static void getInput( ref double loanPayment, ref double insurance, ref double gas, ref double oil, ref double tires, ref double maintenance, ref double monthlyTotal, ref double annualTotal)
{
            Console.WriteLine("How much is the loan payment?");
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out loanPayment))
            Console.WriteLine("Error, enter a number");

            Console.WriteLine("How much is the insurance?");
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out insurance))
                Console.WriteLine("Error, enter a number");

            Console.WriteLine("How much is the gas?");
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out gas))
                Console.WriteLine("Error, enter a number");

            Console.WriteLine("How much is the oil?");
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out oil))
                Console.WriteLine("Error, enter a number");

            Console.WriteLine("How much is the tires?");
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tires))
                Console.WriteLine("Error, enter a number");

            Console.WriteLine("How much is the maintenence?");
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out maintenance))
                Console.WriteLine("Error, enter a number");
}//endgetInput
{
    static void calculate( ref double loanPayment, ref double insurance, ref double gas, ref double oil, ref double tires, ref double maintenance, ref double monthlyTotal, ref double annualTotal);
            monthlyTotal = loanPayment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance;

            annualTotal = monthlyTotal * 12;


        }//endCalculate
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoever is voting to close this should really stop and think if they're being constructive.  Someone is asking for help and that's what this site is for.  To help them.  If you can't spend the time to help, don't come on our site.  Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of fixing up your code a bit.  I factored out most of the redundant logic.  There are more advanced things you could do but I think this version is pretty easy to follow assuming you're using this to learn.  Try to remember an important concept: DRY.  It stands for Don't Repeat Yourself.  Being DRY is a good guideline for whether or not you're doing well when you're beginning:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class ProgramInputs
    {
        public double LoanPayment;
        public double Insurance;
        public double Gas;
        public double Oil;
        public double Tires;
        public double Maintenance;
    }

    class ProgramOutputs
    {
        public double MonthlyTotal;
        public double AnnualTotal;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following expenses on a per month basis");

            ProgramInputs inputs = getInputs();
            ProgramOutputs outputs = calculate(inputs);

            Console.WriteLine("Your monthly total is ${0:F2} and your annual total is ${1:F2}", outputs.MonthlyTotal, outputs.AnnualTotal);
        }

        static ProgramInputs getInputs()
        {
            // make a new program input object
            ProgramInputs inputs = new ProgramInputs();

            // get each input using a convenient method that factors out the parsing logic
            inputs.LoanPayment = getSingleInput("How much is the loan payment?");
            inputs.Insurance = getSingleInput("How much is the insurance?");
            inputs.Gas = getSingleInput("How much is the gas?");
            inputs.Oil = getSingleInput("How much is the oil?");
            inputs.Tires = getSingleInput("How much are the tires?");
            inputs.Maintenance = getSingleInput("How much is the maintenance?");

            // return them in single object, it's neater this way
            return inputs;
        }

        static double getSingleInput(string message)
        {
            double input = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error, enter a number");
            }
            return input;
        }

        static ProgramOutputs calculate(ProgramInputs inputs)
        {
            ProgramOutputs outputs = new ProgramOutputs();
            outputs.MonthlyTotal = inputs.LoanPayment + inputs.Insurance + inputs.Gas + inputs.Oil + inputs.Tires + inputs.Maintenance;
            outputs.AnnualTotal = outputs.MonthlyTotal * 12;

            return outputs;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best practice would be to create a structure or class to keep your data and encapsulate your calculate functions. A skeletal could be

```
public class CarLoan
{
public CarLoan()
{
}

public GetInput()
{
// Input
}

public Calculate()
{
// Calculate loan
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- No need for `ref` you are not using value passed. Use `out` instead
- Don't repeat yourself - extract error message to constant
- double's default value is `0`, no need to initialize with `0`
- (static) methods should be in class body
- Methods with many parameters are not a good idea, even with functional programming style

Here is fixed code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private const string ErrMsg = "Error, enter a number";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, 
               maintenance, monthlyTotal, annualTotal;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following expenses on a per month basis");

        GetInput(out loanPayment, "loan payment");
        GetInput(out insurance, "insurance");
        GetInput(out gas, "gas");
        GetInput(out oil, "oil");
        GetInput(out tires, "tires");
        GetInput(out maintenance, "maintenance");

        Calculate(out monthlyTotal, out annualTotal, loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintenance);

        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Your monthly total is ${0:F2} and your annual total is ${1:F2}", monthlyTotal, annualTotal);
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void GetInput(out double value, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How much is the {0}?", message);
        while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
            Console.WriteLine(ErrMsg);
    }

    private static void Calculate(out double monthlyTotal, out double annualTotal, double loanPayment,
                                  double insurance, double gas, double oil, double tires, double maintenance)
    {
        monthlyTotal = loanPayment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance;
        annualTotal = monthlyTotal * 12;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the opening brace of the `calculate` method before the method signature.

You have put a semicolon at the end of the `calculate` method signature, before the body.